# How a string should start with a capital letter and be more than 2 characters?

Tags: c#, regex

I want to take from the user a string and compare if **it starts with a capital and it has more than 2 letters**.

This is what I wrote so far:

```
string pattern = "^[[:upper:]][[:lower:]A-Za-z]{2}$";
Regex rg = new Regex(pattern);

Console.WriteLine("Give student's firstname");
string sfirstname = Console.ReadLine();
```

Comment: **Do not do this**. “Jo” is a valid first name. So is “x”. It may be silly but **it’s valid**. Don’t validate names. It always goes wrong. See [*Falsehoods programmers believe about names*](https://www.kalzumeus.com/2010/06/17/falsehoods-programmers-believe-about-names/)

Comment: @KonradRudolph Ok i see your point , but this is what my exercise wants.

Answer (score 5):

Note the .NET regex does not support POSIX character classes.

You can achieve that validation without regex:

```cs
if (s.Length > 2 && char.IsUpper(s[0])) {
    Console.WriteLine("{0} is valid!", s);
}
```

Or, if you need a regex:

```cs
if (Regex.IsMatch(s, @"^\p{Lu}..")) {
    Console.WriteLine("{0} is valid!", s);
}
```

Note `^\p{Lu}..` matches a string starting with (`^`) an uppercase letter (`\p{Lu}`) and then having two chars other than a newline char. If you meant to match only lowercase letters, use

```cs
@"^\p{Lu}\p{Ll}{2}"
```

Or, if there can only be lowercase letters after the first letter, use

```cs
@"^\p{Lu}\p{Ll}{2,}$"
```

where `\p{Ll}{2,}$` matches 2 or more lowercase letters at the end of string (`$`).

Comment: I'm always in favor of non Regex solutions when it's simple like this too

Comment: Regex is cool. Readability is cooler. The first option is much easier to understand at a glance. I consider myself *ok* at regex, but I had to look up `\p{Lu}`.

Comment: I'd check for length first. As is, it throws exception when `s` is an empty string.

Comment: @Ortiga This is a piece of code that can be preceded with a `String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace` check.